# Scraping Keyword Suggestions from Google

Tags: php, web-scraping

I'm currently working to scrape keyword suggestion from Google.  This is the script I'm working with:

```
<?php
function text_between($start,$end,$string) {
  if ($start != '') {$temp = explode($start,$string,2);} else {$temp = array('',$string);}
  $temp = explode($end,$temp[1],2);
  return $temp[0];
}
function gsscrape($keyword) {
  $keyword=str_replace(" ","+",$keyword);
  global $kw;
  $data=file_get_contents('http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=firefox&client=firefox&hl=en-US&q='.$keyword);
  $data=explode('[',$data,3);
  $data=explode('],[',$data[2]);
  foreach($data as $temp) {
  $kw[]= text_between('"','"',$temp);
  }
}
#simple to use, just use yourscriptname.php?keywords

if ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']!='') {
  gsscrape($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
  foreach ($kw as $keyword) {
  gsscrape($keyword);
  }

//sorted and duplicates removed
sort(array_unique($kw));

#all results echoed with break
foreach ($kw as $keywords) {
echo $keywords. "<br />";
}

}
?>
```

When accessing directly through the URL Google will give me this response for the keyword `money`:

```
["money",["moneygram","money network","money mutual","money trees lyrics","moneyball","moneypak","money","money converter","money order","money2india"]]
```

However, for some reason when I test it on my website, it's just showing this:

```
moneygram
moneygram
```

What needs to be changed so that it displayed each of the keywords like this?

```
moneygram, money network, money mutual, money trees lyrics, moneyball, moneypak, money, money converter, money order, money2india
```

Comment: You should check out http://scrape-google-suggest.compunect.com/
That is an open source PHP Google suggest scraping spider doing exactly what you want to program and a lot more on top (local caching, resursive spidering, ip management)
Even if you stick to your code, the one I linked might contain functions you will find useful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is valid JSON, use `json_decode` and you are done!

```
var_dump(json_decode('["money",["moneygram","money network","money mutual","money trees lyrics","moneyball","moneypak","money","money converter","money order","money2india"]]'));
```

edit - complete example;

```
<?php

function getKeywordSuggestionsFromGoogle($keyword) {
    $keywords = array();
    $data = file_get_contents('http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=firefox&client=firefox&hl=en-US&q='.urlencode($keyword));
    if (($data = json_decode($data, true)) !== null) {
        $keywords = $data[1];
    }

    return $keywords;
}

var_dump(getKeywordSuggestionsFromGoogle('money'));
```

Comment: How would I use that with the current script?  The results will vary depending on the keyword...

Comment: Well, of course..  You would send the data you get back from Google and have that as input to your json_decode.. This is really simple stuff but I'll update with a complete example..

Comment: That would be amazing!  Sorry for the trouble, just trying to figure this stuff out for the first time :)

Comment: Nice function mate. But why it gives only 10 result. I tried to put num=100 on url but nothing happen. Can you figure it out :)

Comment: What about +20 more ?

Answer (score 3):

To get the data as an array use this:

```
    function gsscrape($keyword) {
      return json_decode(utf8_decode(file_get_contents('http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=firefox&client=firefox&hl=en-US&q='.urlencode($keyword))),true);
     }
```